# Unable to get passport/express to work with LocalStrategy. Get 401

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

I thought I followed the documentation, yet I'm get a 401 response.
I have a simple POST form that receives the 401 response.

This is my sample code (CASE 1):

```
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  console.log("Serializing:", user);
  done(null, JSON.parse(user));
});
passport.deserializeUser(function(obj, done) {
  console.log("Deserializing:" + obj);
  done(null, obj);
});

passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
  function(username, password, done) {
    console.log("Authenticating.....:" + username);
    User.findOne({ username: username }, function(err, user) {
      if (err) { return done(err); }
      if (!user) {
        return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect username.' });
      }
      if (!user.validPassword(password)) {
        return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect password.' });
      }
      return done(null, user);
    });
  }
));

app.post('/auth/login',
passport.authenticate('local'),
  function (req, res) {
    console.log("Made it here");
  }
);
```

The above code never prints any of the messages sent to the console.log. All I see is a message from nodejs/express showing the "POST /auth/login 401" in the console.

The interesting thing is that I changed the app.post function as follows (CASE 2):

```
app.post('/auth/login',
passport.authenticate('local', {
    successRedirect:'/partials/playlist/playlists',
    failureRedirect:'/partials/welcome'
    }),
    function (req, res) {
        console.log("Made it here");
    }
);
```

This time around the only link that gets invoked is the /partials/welcome' redirect as "POST /auth/login 302". Again, no messages logged in the console.

My questions:
Why the different behavior of the two app.post implementations (CASE 1 vs CASE 2)?
Why is my "SucessRedirect" never called in CASE 2?
Why nothing gets printed in the the console.log?

Any ideas?

Comment: You serialize users by "JSON.parse(user)" while you deserialize users by "obj". Usually these two should be consistent. It would be helpful if you have complete code here.